# meaning of --sysroot=$SDKTARGETSYSROOT?

Tags: cross-compiling, yocto

HAve something very puzzling(or sound strange to me). Wish to have some clearer explanation from you guys

Have been cross compiling a file using  environmental-setup-file (environment-setup-aarch64-poky-linux) from a Yocto Distribution for an arm  . I understand it is to set environment (by using source environment-setup-file)

It contains

- SDKTARGETSYSROOT (I understand it is the representative minimal target where it holds the header and library file needed to cross compile the code)
- PATH (somewhat like the PATH usage in your own environment but somewhat different as it is pertaining to the target)

What I find confusing is that the location of toolchain. Isnt it supposed to be found in SDKTARGETSYSROOT (The toolchain is set by others, `SDKTARGETSYSROOT= /opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/environment-setup-aarch64-poky-linux` ) ? I find my aarch64-poky-linux-gcc to be found in directory outside that of SDKTARGETSYSROOT  (though the gcc is found in PATH,, `/opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-poky-linux`)

Is there a rationale for doing this way? I have been coding the codes but would like to learn why this is so?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has got to do more with the cross canadian compiler (GCC in this case) rather than Yocto, the Yocto Project wires its compiler logic  using the `--sysroot` argument passed to GCC:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html

This tells GCC to treat whats passed as `--sysroot` as if it was the sysroot on a typical compilation on target, e.g. usually GCC expects to find headers in /usr/include or libraries in `/usr/lib` , if we pass `--sysroot=/foo/` then it will automatically look at `/foo/usr/include` and `/foo/usr/lib` respectively.

The toolchain scripts in the Yocto Project use `--sysroot=SDKTARGETSYSROOT` to pass the directory where the SDK is installed, hence it finds the proper header and libs to be able to cross compile from the SDK, for more info: https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/tree/meta/classes/toolchain-scripts.bbclass

Now why is GCC outside that directory?, because that directory only contains files for the target architecture (hence `SDKTARGETSYSROOT`, `SDK`: for the SDK, `TARGET`: meant for the target arch, `SYSROOT`: the sysroot to be used), and GCC is not.
GCC is compiled to run in your HOST, hence it doesnt belong in that directory, it is precisely why you see the `x86_64-pokysdk-linux` part of the path where GCC is actually installed in, your HOST triplet is a 64 bit x86 architecture, an SDK built by poky (Yocto), and its OS is Linux.